# antlr lexer rule matching a prefix of another rule

Tags: antlr, antlr3

I am not sure that the issue is actually the prefixes, but here goes.

I have these two rules in my grammar (among many others)

```antlr
DOT_T  : '.' ;
AND_T  : '.AND.'  | '.and.'  ;
```

and I need to parse strings like this:

```
a.eq.b.and.c.ne.d
c.append(b)
```

this should get lexed as:

```
ID[a] EQ_T ID[b] AND_T ID[c] NE_T ID[d]
ID[c] DOT_T ID[append] LPAREN_T ID[b] RPAREN_T
```

the error I get for the second line is:

```
line 1:3 mismatched character "p"; expecting "n"
```

It doesn't lex the `.` as a `DOT_T` but instead tries to match `.and.` because it sees the `a` after `.`.

Any idea on what I need to do to make this work?

**UPDATE**

I added the following rule and thought I'd use the same trick

```
NUMBER_T
    : DIGIT+
        ( (DECIMAL)=> DECIMAL 
        | (KIND)=>    KIND
        )?
    ;

fragment DECIMAL
    : '.' DIGIT+ ;
fragment KIND
    : '.' DIGIT+ '_' (ALPHA+ | DIGIT+) ;
```

but when I try parsing this:

```
lda.eq.3.and.dim.eq.3
```

it gives me the following error:

```
line 1:9 no viable alternative at character "a"
```

while lexing the `3`. So I'm guessing the same thing is happening as above, but the solution doesn't work in this case :S Now I'm properly confused...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that is because of the prefixed `'.'`-s.

Whenever the lexer stumbles upon `".a"`, it tries to create a `AND_T` token. If the characters `"nd"` can then not be found, the lexer tries to construct another token that starts with a `".a"`, which isn't present (and ANTLR produces an error). So, the lexer will ***not*** give back the character `"a"` and fall back to create a `DOT_T` token (and then an `ID` token)! This is how ANTLR works.

What you can do is optionally match these `AND_T`, `EQ_T`, ... inside the `DOT_T` rule. But still, you will need to "help" the lexer a bit by adding some syntactic predicates that force the lexer to look ahead in the character stream to be sure it can match these tokens.

A demo:

```
grammar T;  

parse
 : (t=. {System.out.printf("\%-10s '\%s'\n", tokenNames[$t.type], $t.text);})* EOF
 ;

DOT_T  
 : '.' ( (AND_T)=> AND_T {$type=AND_T;}
       | (EQ_T)=>  EQ_T  {$type=EQ_T; }
       | (NE_T)=>  NE_T  {$type=NE_T; }
       )?
 ;

ID
 : ('a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z')+
 ;

LPAREN_T
 : '('
 ;

RPAREN_T
 : ')'
 ;

SPACE
 : (' ' | '\t' | '\r' | '\n')+ {skip();}
 ;

NUMBER_T
 : DIGIT+ ((DECIMAL)=> DECIMAL)?
 ;

fragment DECIMAL : '.' DIGIT+ ;
fragment AND_T   : ('AND' | 'and') '.' ;
fragment EQ_T    : ('EQ'  | 'eq' ) '.' ;
fragment NE_T    : ('NE'  | 'ne' ) '.' ;
fragment DIGIT   : '0'..'9';
```

And if you feed the generated parser the input:

```
a.eq.b.and.c.ne.d
c.append(b)
```

the following output will be printed:

```
ID         'a'
EQ_T       '.eq.'
ID         'b'
AND_T      '.and.'
ID         'c'
NE_T       '.ne.'
ID         'd'
ID         'c'
DOT_T      '.'
ID         'append'
LPAREN_T   '('
ID         'b'
RPAREN_T   ')'
```

And for the input:

```
lda.eq.3.and.dim.eq.3
```

the following is printed:

```
ID         'lda'
EQ_T       '.eq.'
NUMBER_T   '3'
AND_T      '.and.'
ID         'dim'
EQ_T       '.eq.'
NUMBER_T   '3'
```

### EDIT

The fact that `DECIMAL` and `KIND` both start with `'.' DIGIT+` is not good. Try something like this:

```
NUMBER_T
 : DIGIT+ ((DECIMAL)=> DECIMAL ((KIND)=> KIND)?)?
 ;

fragment DECIMAL : '.' DIGIT+;
fragment KIND    : '_' (ALPHA+ | DIGIT+); // removed ('.' DIGIT+) from this fragment
```

Note that the rule `NUMBER_T` will now never produce `DECIMAL` or `KIND` tokens. If you want that to happen, you need to change the type:

```
NUMBER_T
 : DIGIT+ ((DECIMAL)=> DECIMAL {/*change type*/} ((KIND)=> KIND {/*change type*/})?)?
 ;
```

Comment: @Milan, `lda.eq.3.and.dim.eq.3` *is* properly parsed. See the edited demo in my answer. If it doesn't with you, you'll need to provide the exact grammar that fails (there must be something else going wrong).

Comment: hm... I added another rule that actually broke it... I updated the example above...

Comment: thanks! it worked :)
you have a beer waiting for you in Zurich :)